Basic workflow of topological data analysis and deep learning
I have a confusion regarding applying TDA (topological data analysis) and deep learning to a tabular dataset. As per the usual standard, rows are the points and columns are the features. Feeding this dataset to a neural network model does not give satisfactory classification results. There are reasons to assume that these points might have topological features. So I want to do topological data analysis, extract more features, augment my table with topological features, and then feed the augmented training dataset to a neural network model.
But TDA is done on a point cloud. Let's say I extract a topological feature named T1 from a point cloud consisting of points Row 1 to Row 50. Then I must assign the same value to the cells Row 1 to Row 50 in the table while augmenting a column T1, right? Is this the way to go?
There might be something very basic that I'm missing here. I would really appreciate any insight into the workflow.
